# Unabe to Get OpenStack Login prompt

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-horizon

I have OpenStack UI running. I made some changes in the `local-setting.py` file and restarted the Horizon service using `service httpd restart` and try to hit OpenStack UI but it returns an error: "HTTP 400 Bad request".

When I revert back all changes, restart the service and try again the error is still there.

Please help me !!

Comment: The first thing you need to do is examine your error logs and determine if there are any useful error messages to be found.  For problems with the dashboard, you probably want to look in both your webserver error logs (possibly `/var/log/httpd/error_log` or similar) as well as in the Horizon log at `/var/log/horizon/horizon.log`).  If you find errors, and you are not able to make since of them on your own, post them here and we'll see if we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Total agree with above comments, check your apache or httpd log files.
Most probably error cause due to improper info.

added (for centos)  under below file.
/etc/openstack-dashboard/local_settings

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['XX.XX.XX.XX', 'ControllerName', 'localhost']

Hopefully this will resolve issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running on Horizon on Apache then you need to check apache logs to identify issue. Horizon logs will not contains anything if apache was not able to execute WSGI script for Horizon.